# How can I get $ not escaped in application default jvm args for gradle?

Tags: gradle

Using the application task I am specifying:

```
applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ['$DEBUG_OPTS',
  '-Djava.library.path=${ZMQ_LIB_PATH}']
```

In the generated start scripts I see:

```
DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS='"\$DEBUG_OPTS" "-Djava.library.path=\${ZMQ_LIB_PATH}"'
```

I don't want the `\$` in there.  I tried using `'$$DEBUG_OPTS'` and also `'\$DEBUG_OPTS'` but got the same result.  What is the right way to escape the `$` so it ends up in the script without a backslash in front of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [StartScriptGenerator code](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/plugins/src/main/groovy/org/gradle/api/internal/plugins/StartScriptGenerator.groovy#L67) implies that '$' will be unconditionally replaced by the '\$'.

I assume that your intention is to use '$' character for shell parameters extension but I would like to point out that such usage (if permitted by the gradle task that generates the scripts) is not interoperable between bash and bat scripts - in the bash it will be used for shell parameters extension but in the bat it will have no meaning.

Comment: Interesting.  It's probably better for me to write my own script generator then.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue, trying to add a commandline parameter $1 in there.  With some googling came up with this solution, fixing the script after the fact.

```
applicationDefaultJvmArgs=['-Dmy.property=DOLLARONE']

...

startScripts{
    doLast{
        def bashFile = new File(getOutputDir(),applicationName)
        String bashContent = bashFile.text
        bashFile.text = bashContent.replaceFirst('DOLLARONE',       Matcher.quoteReplacement('$1'))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For Kotlin build script the solution could look like:

```
tasks.named<CreateStartScripts>("startScripts") {
    doLast {
        unixScript.writeText(unixScript.readText().replace("{{APP_HOME}}", "\${APP_HOME}"))
        windowsScript.writeText(windowsScript.readText().replace("{{APP_HOME}}", "%APP_HOME%"))
    }
}
```